# How to read file from local directory path

Tags: c

I have one function which reads file and does the conversion part.

```
fp=fopen("newfile.txt","r");
```

Here i have copied this newfile.txt in project file and compiling in VC++ 2008 IDE.It works fine

I would like to read the file from a local drive directory path.is it possible to read the files from local drive.how to mention the path.If so please mention any example.

one more thing If i want to read all the files in that particular folder with out changing the name of text files in the above code. Suggest me any thing to do.

I dont want to change the file name manully in the code

Comment: `fp = fopen("K:/path/to/source/newfile.txt", "r");` or `fp = fopen("K:\\path\\to\\source\\newfile.txt", "r");`

Comment: If you do not want to change the name in the code, then you should have written the code such that the path passed to fopen was given as a parameter.  Hard coding strings is bad practice, and this is one of the reasons.

Comment: @pmg thanks..It works fine by mentioning the directory path and file name.txt.but what i was trying to ask u is with out changing the newfile.txt in code .how can i access all the files in the mentioned path and process the conversion of all files in path directory.

Comment: You can't. If you don't change the name you cannot open any file named differently, though you may be able to open several files named `"newfile.txt"` in different directories. In POSIX systems you can try [`chdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html) before opening the file ... or [`opendir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html), [`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html), and [`closedir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/closedir.html).

Comment: On Windows (if the POSIX functions don't work there) you have [`SetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ... or [`FindFirstFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and friends (`FindNextFile()`, `FindClose()`).

Answer (score 3):

You could use an absolute path to your file:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("c:\\your_dir\\your_file.txt", "r");
if(fp) {
   // do something
   fclose(fp);
}
```

or a relative path, assuming your file is located in `c:/etc` and your executable is located in `c:/etc/executables`:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("..\\your_file.txt", "r");
if(fp) {
   // do something
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use first program argument. It is a string containing path of executable. You can access it by using`int main(int argc, char *args[])` instead of `int main()`. The args[0] contains what you need. Just take a substring of it, to get the path and concatenate it with your filename.