# An absolute path in fopen()

Tags: c, fopen, filepath

I am trying to make my c program more dynamic. It should opens a file with fopen(). Apparently, fopen does not read absolute paths. For example It can't read this path:

```
fopen("/Documents/projects/cs50_radio/broadcast/source/deadinside.mp3", "r")
```

> returns NULL

;however,

```
fopen("deadinside.mp3", "r");
```

> returns the expected pointer

I was wondering if there is a possible way to read such a path which might be independent from the current working directory in other cases ?

Comment: Did you mean to say Relative Path?

Comment: fopen() can definitely open files using full path spec.  Possibly a typo?

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: Try fopen("\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\"deadinside.mp3" ,"r") or read this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819800/how-to-read-file-from-local-directory-path

Comment: I reviewed my code again and I found out I was not terminating my string which caused this error. thank you all for the replies and sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fopen()` can take absolute paths as arguments. Are you working on a unix/linux based OS or on windows? Likely what is happening is you've got the path wrong. If you're on a mac, which it looks like you are, the correct path might be

```
~/Documents/projects/cs50_radio/broadcast/source/deadinside.mp3
```

But you can verify by cd'ing into the directory and typing `pwd`

If you're on windows, your path is definitely wrong, as windows would look more like this:

```
C:\Documents\projects\cs50_radio\broadcast\source\deadinside.mp3
```

Comment: `~/whatever/you/have/here` is not the path you're looking for. Expansion of `~` to the value of the current user's home directory is usually only done by the shell. Also, IIRC, `/a/path/like/this` works relative to the current working directory's volume in Windows.

Comment: I am actually working on linux, and as you said it was a mistake in the path. I actually forgot to put a null terminator at the end of my string which caused this error. Thank you for your reply

Comment: there is a function that can return the current directory in a string

Comment: @PaulRooney: AFAIK, the Windows API handles both `/` and ``\`` as path component delimiters; it is the `cmd.exe` program that interprets `/` as 'option' and requires ``\`` for path names.  And to show ``\`` in a comment, I typed `…``\\\`\`…` except for the ellipses `…`.  I leave it to you to work out how I entered the explanation.